# How to remove a path from CMake variable set by find_package

Tags: cmake, vtk

#### Problem

I am trying to remove a particular path from CMake variables `VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `VTK_LIBRARIES` that are set by **`find_package(VTK)`**.

In [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/72f41b60a539cd1da67d1329b57222290122a0bb/CMakeLists.txt) of the PCL library, the `VTK` library is first searched by **`find_package(VTK)`**. However, the python path `/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/lib` seems to get in and causes a conflict with `libz.so.1` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. (I believe this is because the `VTK` library was built with Python3 wrapper in the Anaconda environment.):

```sh
cmake ..

...

-- VTK found (
   include: /usr/local/include/vtk-8.2;/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/include/python3.6m,
   lib: vtksys; ...;/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/lib/libpython3.6m.so;vtkPythonInterpreter; ...

...

CMake Warning at cmake/pcl_targets.cmake:263 (add_executable):
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target pcl_generate because
  files in some directories may conflict with libraries in implicit
  directories:

    runtime library [libz.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  tools/CMakeLists.txt:148 (PCL_ADD_EXECUTABLE)
```

#### Try 1

I tried to remove the Python3 path by modifying the `CMakeLists.txt` as follows:

```
if(WITH_VTK AND NOT ANDROID)
  find_package(VTK)
  list(REMOVE_ITEM VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/include/python3.6m")
  list(REMOVE_ITEM VTK_LIBRARIES "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/lib/libpython3.6m.so")
  if(VTK_FOUND)
    ...
    message(STATUS "VTK found (include: ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS}, lib: ${VTK_LIBRARIES}")
```

This *does change* the CMake message that prints out, but doestn't solve the problem; the problem still persists:

```sh
-- VTK found (
   include: /usr/local/include/vtk-8.2,
   lib: vtksys; ...;vtkPythonInterpreter; ...
...
     runtime library [libz.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
      /home/w/.conda/envs/py36/lib
```

#### Question

So `list(REMOVE_ITEM VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS "/home/w/.conda/envs/py36/include/python3.6m")` *does remove* this path from the `VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable, but doesn't seem to change the actual inclue path internally. I must have missed some inportant concept of `CMake`.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: The [search procedure](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure) for the `find_package()` command might be helpful.

Comment: I believe that the reason the Python3 path gets in is because the VTK library is built with the Python3 wrapper. (I built VTK library manually myself.)

Comment: As far as I understand the `... may be hidden by files in` warning, it is not about *wrong* search order. It actually tells: "note, correctness of these library searching is fully depends on search order, which could be very fragile". That is, your program may work (and use proper libraries), or may do not work (when runtime loader chooses a wrong library). It is unlikely that you can fix CMake script for avoid this problem. You need to fix your environment.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I can try to rebuild VTK library again without the Python wrapper. (I suspect that this is the cause of the conflict.) But this means that I won't be able to use VTK library in Python on my machine.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Could you elaborate on what you mean by fixing my environment? I never expose/export the Python3 path while building the PCL library. For some reason, however, this Python3 path is searched and found by CMake.

Comment: By "fixing environment" I mean either removing `libz` from Python environment, so the linker can safely find `libz` under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Or using libraries (including VTK) which doesn't refer to the Python environment.

Comment: Thanks, I tried building the VTK without Python wrapper and the error disappear. But I think that there must be a better solution; to be able to use the existing VTK (with Python3 wrapper) and to use this PCL library.